# Error arises on creating pascal triangle

Tags: haskell

I am facing a problem on creating pascal triangle. The code is given below. Here **sumLstElts** will sum the elements on a row, **putBetween** will put the sum at the right side of the [1]. **pascal n** will give us the series of pascal sequences in a row.

```
    sumLstElts (x:[])=[x]
    sumLstElts []=[]
    sumLstElts xs=[head xs+head(tail xs)]++sumLstElts (tail xs)

    putBetween xs'= [1]++xs''
            where xs''=sumLstElts xs'

    pascal 0=[1]
    pascal n= putBetween(pascal (n-1)) ++ pascal(n-1)
```

Would u pls help me to identify my error?
thnx in advance.

saugata

Comment: What's the error? Does it fail to compile? If so, what's the error message? Does it produce the wrong result? If so, provide examples of input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: Tell us the error message! Also, it would probably help to narrow down the problem if you would use type signatures for your functions.

Comment: I get anser only for pascal nth row. suppose i write pascal 4. it shows [1,4,6,4,1].NOTED DAT at that time i did nt use pascal(n-1)at the end. BUt when i used pascal(n-1) to get the full list of triangle den it shoes abnormal result.SO i m coming here to identify whts da mistake i made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just the n-th row,

```
pascal n= putBetween(pascal (n-1))
```

is the right way, `putBetween` already constructs the complete next row from a given. If you want to create the triangle as a list of rows, something like

```
pascal :: Int -> [[Integer]]
pascal n = take (n+1) $ iterate putBetween [1]
```

would construct the triangle starting with row 0. If you want the part of the triangle in reverse order, longer rows first,

```
pascal :: Int -> [[Integer]]
pascal 0 = [[1]]
pascal n = putBetween top : previous
  where
    previous = pascal (n-1)
    top = head previous
```

does that.

The problem with your attempt is that `putBetween` is applied to the entire result of `pascal (n-1)`, which is intended to contain not only the `n-1`-st row, but also the previous rows. So `pascal 1` gave the concatenation of the first row `[1,1]` with the zeroth `[1]`, and when `pascal 2` applies `putBetween` to that, it's not a row of Pascal's triangle, so the result isn't one either. You could also get the concatenation of the rows by

```
pascal 0 = [1]
pascal n = putBetween (take n previous) ++ previous
  where
    previous = pascal (n-1)
```

but in my opinion it's better to have the triangle as a list of rows.

Comment: u r right. I already get answer only for pascal nth row and its true if i dont include pascal(n-1). BUt when i try to get full list with adding pascal(n-1) den it shows abnormal results.

Comment: I dont get ur last code.MY OBJECTIVE IS TO GET THE FULL TRAINGLE LIST STARTING WITH PASCAL 0

Comment: adding ur last line shows me the following error:                                                                              No instance for (Num [t])
      arising from a use of `pascal' at <interactive>:1:0-7
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [t])
    In the expression: pascal 4
    In the definition of `it': it = pascal 4

Comment: That's what the `iterate` does, `*PascalT> take 4 $ iterate putBetween [1] ~> [[1],[1,1],[1,2,1],[1,3,3,1]]`. Ah, I see. For that, you have to remove the first line, you don't add the line, you replace the definition.

Comment: fantastic daniel. it works now. i just delete da frst line: pascal[0]=1. I am really glad to get da triangle. BUt its not triangle, CAn u pls suggest me how can i create the triangle?

Comment: What do you mean with "create the triangle"? What is the desired result?

Comment: and as a newbie i dont get the use of iterate also

Comment: `iterate` creates a list of repeated applications of a function to a value, `iterate f x = x : iterate f (f x)`, so the result will be `x : f x : f (f x) : f (f (f x)) : ...`.

Comment: sry to dstrb u daniel. I mean that how to give the result a triangle shape? like the pascal triangle we have seen usually?

Comment: That's a matter of displaying, and not of constructing the triangle. It's even complicated to handle the different lengths of the integer representations properly.

Comment: Daniel, I got a code to display the triangle. THe code is like:                                                                                                                                   import Text.Printf
pascal' = iterate (\prev -> 1 : zipWith (+) prev (tail prev) ++ [1]) [1]

pettyPascal n = mapM_ (\r -> printf "%*s\n" (div (longest + length r) 2) r) rows
    where rows = map (unwords . map show) $ take (n + 1) pascal'
          longest = length $ last rows

THE ERROR SHOWS IN MY GHCI6.12.3 IS: parse error on input 'import'

Comment: Is that in a file or are you trying to enter that at the ghci prompt?

Comment: i wrote it down in emacs. den try to compile it

Comment: Not really, but first check the indentation in your file (remove all tabs that are in the file, use spaces). If that doesn't resolve the parse error, that might be a new question. Without seeing the actual file, finding the cause of a parse error is quite hard.

Comment: I m postng it as a question for u. so tht u can see the code.